# Multiple Case statements in SQL

Tags: oracle, case

I've got a basic one for you. I have the syntax broken on the following statement. I don't know how to run two 'case' selects in one statement. I am getting the error: FROM keyword not found where expected.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN`enter code here`
            attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 40
                THEN
                    'Parts Sales'
        ELSE
            'This is blank'
    END AS Parts Sales,
    CASE
        WHEN
            attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 5
                THEN
                    'Aircraft Management'
        ELSE
            'This is blank'
    END AS Aircraft Management,
    cmp.COMPANY_NAME, cmp.ADDRESS1
FROM COMPANIES cmp
LEFT JOIN UDA_CHECKED uda ON uda.AUTO_KEY = cmp.CMP_AUTO_KEY
LEFT JOIN USER_DEFINED_ATTRIBUTES attr ON uda.UDA_AUTO_KEY = attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY
WHERE attr.AUTO_KEY_PREFIX = 'CMP'
```

Comment: Sample output would provide us information we need to properly address your issue

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not in the `CASE`, but in the column aliases.
If you need an alias with a space, you have to use double quotes:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN
            attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 40
                THEN
                    'Parts Sales'
        ELSE
            'This is blank'
    END AS "Parts Sales",
    CASE
        WHEN
            attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 5
                THEN
                    'Aircraft Management'
        ELSE
            'This is blank'
    END AS "Aircraft Management",
   ...
```

otherwise, simply remove the spaces:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN
            attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 40
                THEN
                    'Parts Sales'
        ELSE
            'This is blank'
    END AS PartsSales,
    CASE
        WHEN
            attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 5
                THEN
                    'Aircraft Management'
        ELSE
            'This is blank'
    END AS AircraftManagement,
    ...
```

Comment: That was dumb of me to have that space in there, thanks. It is still giving me the error ' FROM keyword not found where expected.

Answer (score 0):

Updated.

Wrap up your column aliases with a double quote sign `"`.

Entire statement:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 5 THEN 'Aircraft Management' 
       ELSE 'This is blank' END AS "Aircraft Management",
  CASE WHEN attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 40 THEN 'Parts Sales' 
       ELSE 'This is blank' END AS "Parts Sales",
  cmp.COMPANY_NAME, 
  cmp.ADDRESS1
FROM COMPANIES cmp
LEFT JOIN UDA_CHECKED uda ON uda.AUTO_KEY = cmp.CMP_AUTO_KEY
LEFT JOIN USER_DEFINED_ATTRIBUTES attr ON uda.UDA_AUTO_KEY = attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY
WHERE attr.AUTO_KEY_PREFIX = 'CMP'
```

Also, if there is no match consider just dropping the `ELSE` part and leaving column value to be `NULL` instead of putting `This is blank` value.

Comment: I would like two different columns if possible. one for each value.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: That did it! Thank  you.